Why does actual entry arrow trigger late?
Using an RSI strategy which detects bullish divergence, and the actual trade entry (shown by blue arrow) seems to be 4 candles after the trigger (shown by) the "bull" label on the RSI. Is there a way to make the entry trigger immediately?
(https://i.sstatic.net/yAKmjF0w.jpg)
I have little experience with pinescript or any coding, cannot find any lines in the code which look like they would delay an entry. There is nothing about confirmation.

It is a lagging indicator

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
